# Motion of $n$ bodies connected with springs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

Let's consider $n$ cuboids moving without friction, each of mass $m_i$. Each wo neighboring cuboids are connected with a spring of the coefficient $k$.

```
|----|      |---|    |----|     |----|    |-----|
|    |\/\/\/|   |\/\/|    | ... |    |/\/\|     |
|----|      |---|    |----|     |----|    |-----|
```

I came across a assumption that the movement of $i$-th cuboid will be 
$$x_i = A_i \cos(\omega t + \phi_i)$$
assuming the same $\omega$ for each of the cuboids.

Why can we make such an assumption?

Comment: I don't know if I'm going to have time to write a good answer about this, but the fundamental reason is that the system has [normal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode), which, because the differential equation of this system is time translational invariant, have sinusoidal time dependence. I remember being confused about this for years as a student. Keep asking until you get a complete understanding of this, as it's one of the most important topics in physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the final solution looks like that. Rather, you are looking for all the solutions of that form ([normal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode)) for two reasons:

- They are easy to find
- You can afterwards decompose any motion into a sum of normal modes. This comes from writing your equations of motion in the normal basis*.

So first you work out the normal modes by assuming a solution like the one you wrote there. Then you write a system of equations that says the coordinates are a linear combination of the normal modes. 
By evaluating this set of equations at some instant in time, and equating it to a set of initial conditions, you can solve for the amplitude of each normal mode. [Here's a complete worked out example](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/normalmodes.pdf).

It is often enough to know what the normal frequencies are, in order to predict attributes like the [absorption spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_spectrum) of a molecule.

* Your equation has this form: $\frac{d^2\vec x}{dt^2}=A\vec x$. By diagonalizing the symmetric matrix A, you can write it as a diagonal matrix $D$ in a different basis: $A=CDC^T$ ($C$ is the matrix that takes coordinates in the new basis and gives you positions in the old one). Multiplying the original equation by $C^T$ on the left and using $C^TC=\mathbb I$, you get $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}C^T\vec x=DC^T\vec x$. Calling $\vec y=C^T\vec x$ the normal coordinates, you now have a set of uncoupled differential equations: $\frac{d^2y_n}{dt^2}=D_ny_n$. Their solution is $y_n=A_n\sin(\omega_nt+\phi_n)$, with $\omega_n=\sqrt{-D_n}$.

While this proves that you have a basis of normal modes, you don't go through this whole procedure each time. You usually just propose normal mode solutions.

Comment: It would probably help to show why the normal modes are guaranteed to have the sinusoidal dependence OP mentions. This deserves an in-depth and complete description.

Comment: Not all matrices can be diagonalized. How do we know that the matrix $A$ can be diagonalized?

Comment: Moreover, a finite mass-spring system will yield a tridiagonal matrix with equal coefficients on each diagonal. There is an analytical solution to this, which has sin function on the eigenvectors as well
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/AMCS602/tridiag-short.pdf

The eigenmodes show behavior in very similar manner as sound wave would resonate in a pipe, depending on the boundary conditions. Here the end springs connect to fixed position, whereas in the question, the boundaries were open.

Comment: I'll learn about eigenvalues somewhere at the beginning of March (so says the syllabus). Is it possible to show the diagonalization stuff without using the eigenvalues, or should I just simply wait until I learn about them?